# Sequence array initialization with template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I want to initialize an array with a sequence of `int`s from `0` to `N - 1`

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned N>
struct XArray
{
    static constexpr int array[N] = {XArray<N - 1>::array, N - 1};
};

template<>
struct XArray<1>
{
    static constexpr int array[1] = {0};
};


int main(void)
{
    std::array<int, 10> const   a{XArray<10>::array};

    for (int const & i : a)
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I tried that, but it does not work, since `XArray<N - 1>::array` in my struct must be `int`, and not `int *`. How can I do this ? How to "concatenate" the values ?

Comment: This isn't so easy. The language is missing "pack-valued" functions. There were (half-joking) proposals to allow overloading `operator...` for that purpose at some point, but nothing exists in the language at the moment. (E.g. what you'd like is `int array[N] = { unpack<N>()... };`, where `unpack` has an overloaded `operator...`.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Ow... :( No way to do this, so ?

Comment: I only have one word: why

Comment: In other words it's unclear to me if you're specifically trying to make this work or if you're just unaware of how this is usually done.

Comment: I read some things about how it is done, but it is far too complicated for me (and it never works when I try to do it).

Comment: @Boiethios: With `std::array` it's quite doable (as the answer shows). For built-in array types it's a bit trickier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this meets your requirements.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <size_t ...I>
constexpr auto init(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::array<size_t, sizeof...(I)>{I...};
}

int main(void)
{
    std::array<size_t, 10> a = init(std::make_index_sequence<10>());

    for (int const & i : a)
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know `std::index_sequence`, but it is C++14, not 11

Comment: @Boiethios `std::index_sequence` is a pure library extension, you can find C++11 implementations online.

Comment: And you could encapsulate it like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da0aa2c6a1d210f0).

Comment: @TartanLlama Yes, I saw an answer about it, but are they tons of lines necessaries for a so simple thing ?

Comment: At that point though you might as well look at a reference [make_array](https://gist.github.com/lichray/6034753) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `make_array` function template that will return the required `std::array` with elements from `0` to `N-1` as shown below:

##### C++17 Version

```
template<std::size_t N> std::array<int, N> constexpr make_array()
{
    std::array<int, N> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(int &elem:tempArray)
    {
        elem = count++;
    }
    return tempArray;
}
int main()
{
    
    //-------------------------------vv------>pass the size here 
    constexpr auto arr  = make_array<10>();
   

    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: arr)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; //prints 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 with newline in between
    }
    
}
```

[Working demo C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/n6KeK7ds4)

The output of the above program is :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

---

##### C++11 Version

Here the `constexpr` has been removed since `std::array::begin` is not `constexpr` in C++11.

```
template<std::size_t N> std::array<int, N> make_array()
{
    std::array<int, N> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(int &elem:tempArray)
    {
        elem = count++;
    }
    return tempArray;
}
int main()
{
    
    //---------------------vv------>pass the size here 
    auto arr  = make_array<10>();
   

    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: arr)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; //prints 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 with newline in between
    }
    
}
```

[Working demo C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/qazdf87bo)