# calculating data compile time with template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

Suppose we have code like this. It works well and pre-calculate first 5 Fibonacci numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int T>
struct fib;

template <>
struct fib<0>{
    constexpr static int value = 1;
};

template <>
struct fib<1>{
   constexpr static int value = 1;
};

template <int I>
struct fib{
   constexpr static int value = fib<I - 1>::value + fib<I - 2>::value;
};

int main(){
    std::cout << fib<0>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << fib<1>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << fib<2>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << fib<3>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << fib<4>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << fib<5>::value << std::endl;
}
```

However there is "small" problem with it.

What if we need to use this for values, that are not known at compile time?

For few values we can do this:

```
const int max = 5;

int getData(){
   return 5; // return value between 0 and max.
}

int something(){
   switch(getData()){
      case 0: return fib<0>::value;
      case 1: return fib<1>::value;
      case 2: return fib<2>::value;
      case 3: return fib<3>::value;
      case 4: return fib<4>::value;
      case 5: return fib<5>::value;
   }
}
```

This will works OK for 5 values, but what if we have 150 or 300?
Is not really serious to change the code with 300 rows...

What could be the workaround here?

Comment: You could create a static array and look up in runtime as per e. g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297359/sequence-array-initialization-with-template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use a value at runtime that isn't known at compile time, you can't compute it at compile time. Obvious.

But... if you can impose a top value to values needed, you can compute *all* values (from zero to top) at compile time and store them in an `std::array`.

In the following example I have modified your `fib` structs (to use a `std::size_t` index and a template type (with default `unsigned long`) for the value) and I have added a templated `struct fibVals` that contain an `std::array` that is initialized using `fib<n>::value`

The following `main()` show that is possible to define a `constexpr fibvals<N>` (with `N == 20` in the example) to compute (at compile time) all `fib<n>` values in range [0,N[.

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t, typename T = unsigned long>
struct fib;

template <typename T>
struct fib<0U, T>
 { constexpr static T value { T(1) }; };

template <typename T>
struct fib<1U, T>
 { constexpr static T value { T(1) }; };

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct fib
 { constexpr static T value { fib<I-1U>::value + fib<I-2U>::value }; };

template <std::size_t I, typename T = unsigned long>
struct fibVals
 {
   const std::array<T, I>  vals;

   template <std::size_t ... Is>
   constexpr fibVals ( std::index_sequence<Is...> const & )
      : vals { { fib<Is, T>::value ... } }
    { }

   constexpr fibVals () : fibVals { std::make_index_sequence<I> { } }
    { }
 };


int main()
 {
   constexpr fibVals<20>  fv;

   for ( auto ui = 0U ; ui < fv.vals.size() ; ++ui )
      std::cout << "fib(" << ui << ") = " << fv.vals[ui] << std::endl;
 }
```

Unfortunately this example use `std::make_index_sequence<I>` and `std::index_sequence<Is...>` that are C++14 features.

If you want implement `struct fibVals` in C++11, you can implement the following structs `struct indexSeq` and `struct indexSeqHelper`, to substitute `std::index_sequence<Is...>` and `std::make_index_sequence<I>`

```
template <std::size_t ...>
struct indexSeq
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct indexSeqHelper
 { using type = typename indexSeqHelper<N-1U, N-1U, Next ... >::type; };

template <std::size_t ... Next >
struct indexSeqHelper<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = indexSeq<Next ... >; };
```

and implement `fibVals` constructors as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr fibVals ( indexSeq<Is...> const & )
   : vals { { fib<Is, T>::value ... } }
 { }

constexpr fibVals () : fibVals { typename indexSeqHelper<I>::type { } }
 { }
```

Comment: can you explain me what exactly is going on here:
vals { { fib<Is, T>::value ... } } . i tried with different function and it still works OK, but how exactly the ellipsis ... produce an aggregate sequence here?

Comment: doesn't it "fill" the array in run-time?

Comment: @Nick - The ellipsis expand the preceding component with `Is`; in our case `fib<Is, T>::value`. So `vals{ { fib<Is, T>::value ... } }` become `vals{ { fib<0, T>::value, fib<1, T>::value, fib<2, T>::value, fib<3, T>::value, fib<4, T>::value, [...] fib<18, T>::value, fib<19, T>::value } }`

Comment: @Nick - It can "fill" the array compile time or run time, according to the circumstances. My example impose the compile time fill thank to the `constexpr` before `fibVals<20> fv` that impose the compile time construction of `fv`. (continue)

Comment: @Nick - Counter-check: if you remove `constexpr` before one of the two constructors of `fibVal` (preventing it to work compile time) you get a compilation error (from my clang++ "error: constexpr variable 'fv' must be initialized by a constant expression [...] note: non-constexpr constructor 'fibVals' cannot be used in a constant expression"); if you also remove `constexpr` before `fv` definition, the compilation error disappear because `fv` is constructed run-time (or, at least, the compiler is authorized to construct it run-time)

Comment: @Nick For supplementary info on [param pack expansion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), the first 20 minutes of [Going Native 2012 Variadic Templates are Funadic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zgq6_zFNGY) by Andrei Alexandrescu.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are evaluated at compile time, so there is no solution with templates that works at runtime.

You can make a `constexpr` function, which *may* be evaluated at compile time, depending on the value passed. Obviously, a runtime value may not be computed at compile time, as it is not known at compile time.