# Initialize std array with numbers from 1-to N template argument

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a template class and would like to initialize its `std::array` with numbers from `1` to `N` as specified in the argument. How to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<unsigned int N>
class Jollo
{
private:
    std::array<int,N> deck;
public:
    Jollo()
    {
        static_assert(N>1,"Jollo: deck size must be higher than '1'");
        deck = std::array<int,N>{1...N}; //how to do this? = {1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
    }

};

int main()
{
    Jollo<15> j;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile time instantiation (a bit more than what you ask for): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297359/sequence-array-initialization-with-template

Comment: You can use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694579/use-stdfill-to-populate-vector-with-increasing-numbers (similar question but with a vector).

Comment: Off-topic but your `static_assert` should probably be at class level, not in the constructor.

Comment: @Holt I think it's okay, it won't compile if value is <=1

Comment: It works, but it's more idiomatic to put `static_assert` at class level if they refer to class template arguments. If the constructor was templated, this may not work, e.g., https://godbolt.org/z/DLP_Ew

Comment: Oh, I was mistaken, my constructor was incorrect. Thank you!

Comment: Should I use std::size_t instead of unsigned int?

Comment: Standard containers tends to use `std::size_t` (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array for instance), so I would use it, but it's opinion mainly.

Comment: also SFINAE `template<size_t N, std::enable_if_t< (N > 1), int > = 0>`. Although the error message is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) is what you're looking for:

```
Jollo()
{
    static_assert(N>1,"Jollo: deck size must be higher than '1'");
    std::iota(deck.begin(), deck.end(), 1); // fills array from 1 to N
}
```

If constexpr is required, I would go for a loop, since iota is not marked constexpr yet:

```
constexpr Jollo()
{
    static_assert(N>1,"Jollo: deck size must be higher than '1'");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i) {
        deck[i] = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and I cannot wait for C++20 [iota_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `make_array` function template that will return the required `std::array` with elements as per your requirements as shown below. Note just for debugging purposes I've made `deck` public, you can change it back to `private` if required.

##### C++11 Version

```
template<std::size_t N> std::array<int, N> make_array()
{
    std::array<int, N> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(int &elem:tempArray)
    {
        elem = ++count;
    }
    return tempArray;
}

template<unsigned int N>
class Jollo
{
public:
    std::array<int,N> deck; //for debugging purposes i made this public, you can change it back
public:
//-----------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--->use member initializer list
    Jollo(): deck(make_array<N>())
    {
        static_assert(N>1,"Jollo: deck size must be higher than '1'");
        
    }

};
int main()
{
    Jollo<15> j;
    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: j.deck)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; 
    }
    
}
```

[Working demo C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/dzqGhrzMP)

The output of the above program is :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

---

##### C++17 Version

With C++17, you can do all this at **compile time**(if required) as shown below. The function template `make_array` has been made `consexpr`

```
//-----------------------------------------VVVVVVVVV---------->constexpr added 
template<std::size_t N> std::array<int, N> constexpr make_array()
{
    std::array<int, N> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(int &elem:tempArray)
    {
        elem = ++count;
    }
    return tempArray;
}

template<unsigned int N>
class Jollo
{
public:
    std::array<int,N> deck; 
public:
//--vvvvvvvvv---------------------->constexpr added 
    constexpr Jollo(): deck(make_array<N>())
    {
        static_assert(N>1,"Jollo: deck size must be higher than '1'");
        
    }

};
int main()
{
    constexpr Jollo<15> j;
    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: j.deck)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; 
    }
    
}
```

[Working demo C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/csEzrEnca)