# C++: std::generate in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I like to use std::generate for creating std::vectors. I think it is a fairly clean approach:

```
std::vector<Foo> v(5);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), generator );
```

However, from a performance point of view, this doesn't seem great though since we allocate and initialize all of the vector elements, and then go back and replace them. Ideally, there would be a constructor that took a size and a generator function, but there doesn't seem to be one (something like `v(5, generator)`). Am I missing something obvious?

For cases where one is really concerned about performance (and where construction is expensive), one can do something like this:

```
std::vector<Foo> v;
v.reserve(5);
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
   v.emplace_back(..);
```

Another alternative would be to use a back inserter or something like that, but that would dynamically resize the vector, which also seems far from ideal.

To be clear, the size is not a compile-time argument, so I can't use an std::array. Furthermore, I would strongly prefer to stay away from raw arrays or pointers (where one could perhaps allocate memory with initializing the memory).

A C++11 solution would be preferred, but a C++14 solution would perhaps also be feasible.

Comment: *but that would dynamically resize the vector* - What's stopping your from reserving the capacity in advance here too?

Comment: Thats true. The tricky part would be getting the back inserter to stop I guess. I never really looked into it.

Comment: You have clearly spent some time looking for the answer, that's good. But let's not forget premature optimization is also bad practice. That being said, `std::vector` is a header only implementation, so the compiler might drastically optimize your code, maybe to the point that the initial initialization of all objects never takes place. The only way to know for sure is to disassemble...

Comment: You might also be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297359/sequence-array-initialization-with-template

Comment: A little bit different since that is a constexpr implementation, so there is guaranteed to be no runtime overhead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This look like a use case for the [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) algorithm. It accepts an output iterator (such as a `back_insert_iterator`) and a size. If we reserve the size in advance, we can generate the elements with a generator without reallocation.

```
std::vector<Foo> v;
v.reserve(5);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 5, generator);
```